# How to create a processinstance using spring boot application in JBPM

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, jbpm, rhpam

I have downloaded JBPM 7.62 version.I am changed the database to postgres.I am run my application standalone.bat and business-central is now accessible at http://localhost:8080/business-central/kie-wb.jsp.
I have created one spring boot application.Added the below dependencied:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.62.0.Final</version> <!-- Use the latest version
            available -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>7.62.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.62.0.Final</version> <!-- Use the latest version available -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.62.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>7.62.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
            <version>7.62.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have created one application file that has following code :

```
      KieContainerResource containerResource = kieServicesClient
                          .getContainerInfo("demoproject_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT").getResult(); 
       KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get(); 
 kieContainer =kieServices.newKieContainer(containerResource.getReleaseId());
    // Start a process instance 
  ProcessInstance processInstance =                   kieContainer.newKieSession().startProcess("demoproject.sample");
                          // Get the process instance ID 
Long processInstanceId =processInstance.getId();
```

But how my application will connect to business central and initiate process instance there ? and also it adds entry in database ? Any properties need to configure ? any class to configure ?